# How. to iterate list(map(list)) in terraform

Tags: list, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, foreach, terraform

I want to create files(key) in s3. By below code, I can successfully create the files in s3 -

```
locals {
  rules = [
  {
    user = "user-1",
    roles = "test"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "this" {

  for_each    = zipmap(local.rules.*.user, local.rules.*)
   bucket      = "test-09129"
   acl         = "private"
   source      = "/dev/null"
   key         = "${each.value.roles}/${each.key}"
}
```

file in s3 - test/user-1 created

But roles can be multiple so I create list for roles.

```
locals {
  rules = [
  {
    user = "user-1",
    roles = ["test"]
  },
  {
    user = "user-2",
    roles = ["test", "dev", "prd"]
  }]
}
```

Now I want to create files based on above list. How to iterate list(roles) to create files based on user and role?
desire output -

```
file in s3 -
test/user-1 
test/user-2 
dev/user-2
prd/user-2
```

Comment: The error is not related to your local. What is the full resource that you use `roles_associate` in?

Comment: I am using aws_s3_bucket_object resource.

Comment: If you check [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_object), there are no `roles_associate` in `aws_s3_bucket_object`, which results in your errors.

Comment: I thought, dynamic block can use in any resources. I am updating the question, might you have some solution.

Comment: The dynamic blocks can only be used on blocks supported by a given resource. In your case, your are using un-known block in `aws_s3_bucket_object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten your `rules` into `helper_rules` (assuming I understand correctly your desired outcome):

```
locals {
  rules = [
  {
    user = "user-1",
    roles = ["test"]
  },
  {
    user = "user-2",
    roles = ["test", "dev", "prd"]
  }]
  
  
  helper_rules = merge([
      for user, rules in zipmap(local.rules.*.user, local.rules.*.roles):
         { for rule in rules:
           "${user}-${rule}" => {user = user, rule = rule}
         }
  ]...)
}
```

This will result in `helper_rules`:

```
{
  "user-1-test" = {
    "rule" = "test"
    "user" = "user-1"
  }
  "user-2-dev" = {
    "rule" = "dev"
    "user" = "user-2"
  }
  "user-2-prd" = {
    "rule" = "prd"
    "user" = "user-2"
  }
  "user-2-test" = {
    "rule" = "test"
    "user" = "user-2"
  }
}
```

With that, your objects could be:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "this" {

  for_each     = local.helper_rules
   bucket      = "test-09129"
   acl         = "private"
   source      = "/dev/null"
   key         = "${each.value.role}/${each.value.user}"
}
```

Comment: @lucy This means that probably your `local.rules` in the question is different then what you actually have. I run the code myself, and the flattening works, thus I could post its outcome.

Comment: Awesome man. You are really expert. One question what is 3 dots in helper_rules?

Comment: @lucy No problem. The dots are argument expansion. So `merge([a,b,c]...)` becomes `merge(a,b,c)`.